# Can i know on which machines my WCF services running?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have `WCF service` installed on windows services, this services installed on several machines and from the client side i want to know all the machines `IP addresses` that my service running, is it possible ?

Comment: no, unless, you write an extra code in your service to log the caller either in a file or in database.

Comment: So the only thing i can do (except your solution) is to catch the exception of no endpoint found ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WS-Discovery protocol, WCF implements it. But first, you will have to add a "discovery endpoint" to your WCF service.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: More details, and an example, are available here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx